# problems with storybook with Background parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I'm on a project with a storybook and I want my story to be able to change the background or put a background whatever since I only need a background of a different color but I can't put background as it says in the documentation:

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/backgrounds

```
export default {
  title: 'Button',
  parameters: {
    backgrounds: {
      default: 'twitter',
      values: [
        { name: 'twitter', value: '#00aced' },
        { name: 'facebook', value: '#3b5998' },
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

and my code is like this:

```
export default {
  title: "Atoms/Example",
  component,
  parameters: {
    backgrounds: {
      default: "black",
      values: [
        { name: "black", value: "#000000" },
        { name: "white", value: "#ffffff" }
      ]
    }
  },
  argTypes: {
    is: {
      control: {
        type: "select",
        options: [25, 33, 50, 75, 100]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but my code does not work at all and seeing from the documentation everything is correct.

or if there is any way to put a background to my story even if it is not dynamic if not a fixed one

Comment: feel like there is something else, because your code above should work.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have `@storybook/addon-backgrounds` installed and in the `.storybook/main.js` file make sure its in your addons: `addons: ['@storybook/addon-backgrounds']`

Note make sure its:
`addons: ['@storybook/addon-backgrounds']`
and not
`addons: ['@storybook/addon-backgrounds/register']`

using `register` was the old way and will prevent it from working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this before, but it looks like in your case, you didn't specify which component to render in the `component` property of your [Component Story Format](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/csf) export.

```
export default {
  title: "Atoms/Example",
  component, // <- Component not specified

  // Other properties here...
}
```

Try specifying the component like so, and see if the problem persists.

```
export default {
  title: "Atoms/Example",
  component: Button, // <- Component to render added

  // Other properties...
}
```